# execute a function infinity in javascript

Tags: javascript, fadein

I am trying to fade in a spinner infinity. But spinner will fade out after a time because infinity is not working. My code as follows.

```
setInterval(function(){
        console.log("fergergerg");
        $("#spinner").fadeIn();
},Infinity);
```

Where I was wrong and how can I make my spinner to be faded in always?

Simply I needed something like below.

```
while(true){
   $("#spinner").fadeIn();
}
```

But it also not working.

Comment: The second parameter of `setInterval` indicates how many milliseconds bewteen calls to the function. Do you really want to call the function after Inifinity milliseconds?

Comment: What does it mean to "fade infinity"? Fading in or out, by nature, is a progressive action that starts (when the element is invisible [in] or visible [out]), continues for a time (as the element gets more and more / less and less visible), and ends (when the element is fully visible / no longer visible). It doesn't make sense for it to be fading forever. If you want your element to be invisible, just call `fadeOut` with the time you want that to take; if you want it to be visible, just call `fadeIn` with the time you want that to take.

Comment: I have updated my question to be more clear. Simply I need to execute a function always.

Comment: Infinity is a concept, not a number (though `Infinity` is Type number). If it takes an infinite amount of time to fade, then you will not see it fade at all in an entire lifetime. If it starts to fade at all, even after a thousand years, that infers that at some point it will fade completely, so not infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
The solution is here, the below function executes "load" function every 1000 ms (every 1 sec) for ever and infinite.

function load(){
    $("#spinner").fadeIn();
    setTimeout(load, 1000);
}; load();
```

you can change the interval time as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're misunderstanding what setInterval does. It's meant to execute whatever function you provide it every x number of milliseconds.

By default, elements are shown on the page. Please include your HTML and CSS if the object is not showing up so we can take a look and tell you the root issue.